# Hide a button from a view - setHidden does no work

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I want to hide a button in a window: I have tried the following code it doesn't work

```
var myButton = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainWindow> #mytab> #submitbuttonid')[0];
myButton .setHidden(true);
```

Help?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [hide()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-hide) method to hide the component.

```
var myButton = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainWindow> #mytab> #submitbuttonid')[0];
myButton.hide();
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to pass a boolean parameter, you can use [setVisible](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-setVisible)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:
Take the reference of the button in controller like :

```
myButton: 'button[name="name_of_btn"]'
```

And when you are adding that window to the viewport, do the below after adding:

```
this.getMyButton().hide();
```

Or you can do the above on "activate" or "initialize" event of that window.

Comment: That is great Victor.